# Cannot invoke method isLoggedIn() on null object

Tags: grails, spring-security

I actually have two spring security related question.

1, I have the below code in my controller for changing password

```
def changePassword() {

        if (!securityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect(action: 'auth', controller: 'login')
            return
        }
}
```

when i hit save button after confirming the new password it generates te following error

```
NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [POST] 
Cannot invoke method isLoggedIn() on null object.
```

Now My question is where am i wrong?

2, my second question is also similar am trying to get the current user like this

```
User currentUser = securityService.getCurrentUser()
            currentUser.gender = gender
            currentUser.save()
```

But still its generating the same error
Cannot invoke method getCurrentUser() on null object

**NOTE:-** I am using grails 2.4.4 and spring security 2.0-RC4.

**UPDATE:-**  I did include `def securityService` in my controller/service

Comment: You need to include spring security service simply add 'def springService' in your class

Comment: sorry for not mentioning but I did include def springService.

Comment: I guess it should be springSecurityService

Comment: @AnantKolvankar yeah i just tried it. its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 'def springSecurityService' in your controller

```
Class UserController{

  def springSecurityService

  def changePassword(){
      //You can access springSecurityService now
    if (!springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        redirect(action: 'auth', controller: 'login')
        return
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SpringSecurityService is autowired to controllers this way:

```
   def springSecurityService
```

And with Groovy, you can call `springSecurityService.currentUser` instead of `getCurrentUser()`

Comment: I just tried springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()   and now its working.